# What is the difference between HAL and udev?

Tags: linux, hardware, udev

As far as I understand, if I have 3 different network cards, then HAL will cal each of them eth0, eth1 and eth irrespective of their brands, manufacturerers etc. But it seems to me that udev precisely performs similar operations based on its rules. What is their essential difference(except that HAL is deprecated)?

Comment: `udev` basically replaces `hal`. There isn't much reason for it anymore. Your description of `hal` is what `udev` has been doing in distros for 8+ years.